# How to check special character in array?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, preg-match, strpos

I want to create a condition for special characters. If we find a special character in **array** then display **error message** otherwise display **success message**.
My array is below :

```
Array
(
 [0] => PRIVATE LIMITED
 [1] => *^%$32407
 [2] => 104810170620123
 [3] => 104810170620123
 [4] => 
 [5] => *)@!#CID010
 [6] => SURYA
 [7] => 2016-06-14 08:17:49   
 [8] => 840
 [9] => INR
}
```

So I want condition like this.

```
if(Special char found){
   echo "Special char found";
}else{
   echo "Special char not found";
}
```

I want to output like below :

```
Array
(
 [0] => PRIVATE LIMITED
 [1] => 32407
 [2] => 104810170620123
 [3] => 104810170620123
 [4] => 
 [5] => CID010
 [6] => SURYA
 [7] => 2016-06-14 08:17:49   
 [8] => 840
 [9] => INR
 }
```

Comment: what is the special char?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "special character", cause what should be "special" about it? There are only characters, lots of 'em buggers. So please define which characters you want to accept or which you want to deny.

Comment: if we found special char ( '/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/' ) then display message

Comment: so you mean a character from that list? Or that exact string

Comment: OK, that looks like you already got your answer!

Comment: In array[1], array[5] have a special character.

Comment: ok will adjust my answer

Comment: But I wont to know how can I take condition for that if available then?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand the question

Comment: Why is £ "special" but apparently not ¥? Or €? Or 円? What criterion are you applying to a character to make it "special"? I hope you're not just pulling some random characters out of thin air which happen to pop into your head. Because there's close to a million more of those things, and you should have a logical approach for why you consider *some* special and not others.

Answer (score 1):

You could either loop through the array or use `PHP's`, `in_array` function as followed;

```
if(in_array($sSpecialChar, $aArray)){
    echo 'special char found';
}else{
    echo 'special char not found';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over your array and check with a regexp.

```
foreach ($myArray as $item) {
    if(preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $item)) {
        echo "Special char found.";
    } else {
        echo "Special char not found.";
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't display "Special char not found" if it's not found.

Comment: @Barmar I was expecting a little bit thinking - probably I expected too much. Nevertheless, I updated by answer. Now it displays `Special char not found.` Sorry I did not mean it rude.. but writing an `else` statement should be possible.

Comment: Now it will display both messages multiple times.

Comment: This is a common error that frequently occurs in programs that are searching for something -- they report that it's not found for each element that doesn't match, even though it may be found in a different element.

Comment: You can't tell that it's not found until the **end** of the loop.

Comment: @Barmar If special chars occur multiple times in the array it is just logical to print it multiple times, isn't it? --- "You can't tell that it's not found until the end of the loop." .. uhh, good point!

Comment: I assume the goal is to print a single message indicating whether there were any special characters anywhere in the array, not one message for each element.

Comment: Probably your assumption is right. Then your solution/answer would fulfil the requirement without any doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the array, checking for the special characters and removing them. Use a variable to record if you found any special characters.

```
$special_found = false;
foreach ($array as &$string) { // Use a reference so assignment will update the array
    if (preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬]/', $string) {
        $special_found = true;
        $string = preg_replace('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬]/', '', $string);
    }
}
if ($special_found) {
    echo "Special char found";
}else{
    echo "Special char not found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You needed **condition**:

```
preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/',$array_value)
```

The work:

```
var_export(array_map(function($a){
     return preg_replace('/[\'!^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/','',$a);
},array(
 'KAYA LIMITED','*^%$32407',
 '104810170620123','104810170620123',
 '','*)@!#CID010','HDFC Bank','2016-06-14 08:17:49',   
 '840','INR'
)));
```

Don't change your question;)

In you comment the char `-` is a special char too!
So array[1], array[5] and array[7] have special chars.

Comment: @deceze The escaped backslash or what? If tested it and it works!

Comment: Yes. Even the syntax highlight breaks on it. The entire regex should be red (a string literal), but it's ending the string at `'`.

Comment: *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!', expecting ',' or ')' in /in/d9Xcl on line 4* https://3v4l.org/d9Xcl

Comment: OK fine i missed the `'` :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can create a function to check the special char in the array.

```
function checkSpecialChar($array,$pattern){
    foreach($array as $k=>$val){
        if (preg_match($pattern, $val)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// define a pattern 
$pattern = '/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬]/';
if(checkSpecialChar($array,$pattern)){
    echo "Special char found";
}else{
    echo "Special char not found";
}
```

Above pattern will not consider date format as special char.